# Delphi RichEdit, get y-pixel start of an arbitrary line

Tags: delphi, line, richedit, trichedit

I have a richedit containing lines using different fonts, styles, languages etc.

I am drawing in a gutter. I would like to start my drawing at the same y pixel position as the corresponding line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Send the control an `em_PosFromChar` message. It returns the client coordinates of the character at the given index, although [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761631.aspx) doesn't say what the coordinates represent (upper left corner, baseline center, or what). You're looking for the character's *baseline*.

Use [`em_LineIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761611.aspx) to get a character index for a given line number, if you don't already know the index of a character you're interested in.

Comment: +1. I looked, and this message wasn't listed in the [docs for the RichEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787605%28VS.85%29.aspx) on MSDN, but a Google search turned up a link to it there (the one you posted, BTW). (I thought I remembered something like it, but couldn't quite come up with the message name, and figured I'd remembered wrong when I couldn't find it in the docs.) :-)

Comment: Thanks! It works :) Example code: char_idx := Perform(EM_LINEINDEX, line_idx, 0); Perform(EM_POSFROMCHAR, WPARAM(@char_pt), char_idx); ARect.Top := char_pt.y; ARect.Bottom := ARect.Top + letter_height;